# Can version tags be removed if a question can be modified to be general to all versions?

Tags: discussion, tags

The question [Are there any good programs to learn Dvorak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30833/are-there-any-good-programs-to-learn-dvorak/789392#789392) has a `10.04` tag, but this is a general question that really shouldn't be specific to a particular version of Ubuntu.  Can questions like this be edited to make them more general, and the tag removed?  If so, is there any protocol to taking such an action?

Comment: I would remove those tags if there's nothing version specific in there. In fact, there are almost no problem that is version specific that it isn't also off topic, because is either a bug or EOL'd.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, and I believe version tags should be avoided as much as possible anyways. They make the question have a limited value.

I would even go as far as believing that removing versions from title and body is valid if those have nothing to do with the problem.

Only if it is apparent that the question is off topic (due to the version for instance) leave it there.

We are here to answer questions. If fixing up a question makes for a better answer all the better.

Answer (score 8):

Certainly. Many canonical posts started off with a version tag and grew more general. Personally, I remove those tags if the question's answers now cover multiple versions of Ubuntu, and people have shown an inclination to add answers for versions yet-to-be-covered. When I do that, I also remove the version numbers mentioned in the body or title of the question.

I suggest the following checklist:

- Do the answers cover multiple Ubuntu versions?
- Have answers been added to cover versions released after the question was asked?
- Does the question itself cover multiple versions?

If any of those is true, nuke the tags.

The tags only make sense when the a solution must work for that tag - and if that's been handled, there's not much use for it.

Comment: I like your spirit, but you got it backwards. There's almost no problem that is specific to a version of Ubuntu, and those that are is because the software a) is riddled with bugs b) isn't production ready. Most of LTS tagged questions shouldn't have the version tags.